# How to handle the conflicts between UITapGesture and 3D Touch in iPhone 6s/6s plus?

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

`UITapGesture` works OK for me before I tried it on iPhone 6s.

Please find the below code.

```
tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Then, I met this issue, the `handleTapGesture` will not be invoked in iPhone 6s. I think it's because the **Force Touch** functionality of iPhone 6s.
Anybody know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Please refer the link http://www.basedb.net/Index/detail/id/659682.html

Comment: The doc said：The best way is stop the 3d touch while your app is launched : As per the apple documentation you can see this here :Apple Docs A user can turn off 3D Touch while your app is running, so read this property as part of your implementation of the traitCollectionDidChange: delegate method. But I still can not find any API to turn off 3D Touch in code.